# DataInputStream/InputStream reading data more than once

Tags: java, android, sockets

Having trouble reading data more than once from the current input stream. The server / service it is connecting to uses `libevent` for event driven read and writes. However the writeEvent is never received after the initial packet has been received with the below code snippet:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try  {
                        do {
                            Log.d("Socket", "Entering a new read" + socketInputStream.available());
                            // each packet begins with a packetID, UInt32
                            int newPacketID = socketInputStream.readInt();
                            newPacketID = Integer.reverseBytes(newPacketID); // to little endian
                            int packetLength = socketInputStream.readInt();
                            packetLength = Integer.reverseBytes(packetLength);
                            byte[] payload = new byte[packetLength];
                            socketInputStream.readFully(payload);
                            Log.d("Socket", "Read: " + newPacketID);
                            Log.d("Socket", "Length: " + packetLength);
                            Log.d("Socket", "Payload: " + payload.toString());
                            payload = null;
                            //socketOutputStream.write(0);
                            //socketOutputStream.flush();
                            //socketInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        } while( isConnected == true );
                        Log.d("Socket", "Got away from the loop");
                    } catch(Exception exc) {
                        Log.d("Socket", "Reading exception: " + exc.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            }).start();
```

Uncommenting the single 0 byte + flush from the outputStream does mark the socket for writing again, but I'm wondering how I can achieve the same result without such a hacky method. Why does Java not allow this socket to be read from again?

Is it because the Thread is blocking the socketInputStream from being used anywhere else (thus allowing the socket to mark itself to be available for writing again)?

In more detail, the server has a sendBuffer it tries to empty every time the socket is marked for writing. It will write everything it can and then wait for a new writeevent, check if data is available and start sending if that is the case. If there is no writable socket currently available, the server fills the sendBuffer till such time a new write event can empty it.

```
func checkForData() {
        guard canWrite == true else {
            socketWriteEvent.add() // Make sure we know when we can write again!
            return
        }
        guard sendBuffer.count > 0 else { return }
        canWrite = false

        //let maxChunkSize = 20240 > sendBuffer.count ? sendBuffer.count : 20240

        var bytesWritten = 0
        var totalWritten = 0
        repeat {
            let chunk = Array(sendBuffer[totalWritten..<sendBuffer.count])
            print("Write being executed")
            bytesWritten = tls.write(chunk, count: chunk.count)
            totalWritten += bytesWritten
            print("Still in the write loop")
        } while( bytesWritten > 0 && (totalWritten < sendBuffer.count) )

        if totalWritten > 0 {
            sendBuffer.removeFirst(totalWritten)
        }
        if bytesWritten < 0 {
            let error = tls.context.contextError()
            if error.isEmpty == false {
                print("[TLS] Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        print("Write completed");
        socketWriteEvent.add()
   }
```

Comment: `Why does Java not allow this socket to be read from again? ` Of course you can read from a socket again. But is the server sending anything? What happens? Does it hang somewhere? Timeout exception? You did not tell what happens.

Comment: `Is it because the Thread is blocking the socketInputStream from being used anywhere` That would be a tricky idea to use that stream on different places. Why are you doing so?

Comment: The server never receives a new writeEvent, causing the sendBuffer to slowly fill up. I am only experiencing this problem with this socket implementation. Any unix socket based clients I have lying around work just fine. It is basically epoll() never receiving the required event to start writing again.

Comment: If your client does not write then why do you think the server would generate a write event? Is that called a write event on the server? I would call that a receive event.

Comment: The write event is only for the server side, so it knows it can write more data without blocking or failing. It should not be related to any data the client sends or not. Any data sent by the client is handled by the read events on the server.

Comment: So it seems to me that your server only sends once. Only one message. Then i dont understand you are blaming Android for not receiving the second message. Just put that message twice in the send buffer and you will see that your Android client receives both.

Comment: Because the problem lies specifically in the way I implemented this socket in java. Everything else works and responds fine. Disabling the event driven nature of the server would cause many other problems, even replacing it with other methods of doing async reads and writes would cause the same problem. Blocking IO is simply not the answer for a server.

Comment: I did not ask you to change your server. I asked you to do a test.